# iPad Retina Simulator Gives Different Output Than All Others for NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've run this exact same code on all the other iPad simulators & iPhone and it works fine. However, when I run on the iPad Retina emulator, it gives a different response

```
               NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
               [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
               NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
               NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
               [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
               dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:savedTime];
               NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
               NSInteger time = timeInMiliseconds;

               NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)time];
               NSLog(@"The Date is = %@",savedTime);
               NSLog(@"The Timestamp is = %@",strTimeStamp);
```

This then returns: 
The Date is = 2016/03/03 20:55:39.613
The Timestamp is = -2147483648

Where as if this were on any other simulator it would be correct and return:
The Date is = 2016/03/03 20:55:39.613
The Timestamp is = 1457038539613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSinteger` isn't big enough to hold your value on 32-bit systems. Use a data type that will hold 64-bits regardless of platform. Or just use the `NSTimeInterval`.

```
NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", timeInMilliseconds];
```

Answer (score 0):

On a 32 bit device, NSInteger is 32 bits, and you can see that 1457038539613 doesn't fit into 32 bits.

I would really, really recommend that you don't try to convert NSTimeInterval into some other format. Just leave NSTimeInterval as a double counting seconds. Using the type NSTimeInterval for a number that means milliseconds is close to criminal.